# Error: Could not find or load main class when JAVA_OPTS in setenv.sh

Tags: java, tomcat

I get this error whenever I do anything even this simple with JAVA_OPTS in Tomcat's setenv.sh

`Error: Could not find or load main class`

`#!/bin/sh
export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xmx1024m "`

Causes that error. Ideas?

Comment: Can you try this JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -server -Xmx1024m"

Comment: was this ever resolved? getting same error in Mac OS, on java 11

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot, can you add an *echo* statement at the final java execution ? Alternatively, you can invoke the script using *bash -x*

Answer (score -2):

You have to fix you classpath, just include the jar which contains the Main class (the class that contains the main method) in the classpath. Like this:

```
java -cp jar1;jar2 com.company.Main
```

All about setting the classpath is here : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html